# Mysql update query is taking forever to complete

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, my.cnf

I killed the query after 48 hours..

```
TableA = with 15Million rows (temp_pull_newconsumer_boatowners)
TableB = 131060747 rows (master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final)

#===============================================
UPDATE temp_pull_newconsumer_boatowners a,master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final b
SET a.email = b.reg_email
WHERE a.primaryaddress=b.DeliveryLine1
AND a.personlastname=b.reg_lastname
AND LEFT(a.personfirstname,1) = LEFT(b.reg_firstname,1)
AND a.cityname=b.city
AND a.state =b.state
AND IFNULL(b.DeliveryLine1,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.primaryaddress,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_email,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.personfirstname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_firstname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.personlastname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_lastname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.cityname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.city,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.state,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.state,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.email,'')=''
#==============================

=========Explain Extended===============

          id: 1 
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
         type: ALL
possible_keys: inddddddd_09,ind_909090900999
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 15144363
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: b
         type: ref
possible_keys: ind_999900_0090_I,ind_9090909999,ind_9090909999Ti
          key: ind_999900_0090_I
      key_len: 103
          ref: load_file.a.primaryaddress
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where




-All table fields are of varchar type
-Fields are properly Indexed 
-16GB memory
-It takes about 25 minutes to update 5k records
(if i add an ID (primary key) field in the tableA and update on a condition 
where id between 1 and 500000 )
-There is no conversion happening (checked in explain extended warning)
-The issue started since i moved mysql data directories to another drive (same type of SSD)


below is my.cnf

[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/mysqldata
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

# Fine Tuning

innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

#==========================================
```

I see its scanning 15M rows, how can i check how much has been scanned so far?
What config my.cnf changes i can make to expedite the query?

I SUSPECT THE PROBLEM IN IN MY.CNF SINCE THE ISSUE STARTED RIGHT AFTER I MOVED THE DATA DIRECTORIES TO ANOTHER DRIVE, ALSO THERE MAY BE SOME CHANGES WHICH I MIGHT HAVE MADE IN THE GLOBAL VARIABLES WHICH I DIDNT MAKE SINCE I RESTART MYSQL SERVICES, DONT REMEMBER THEM NOW.

Below is show create table for both tables.....

```
CREATE TABLE `master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final` (
  `reg_source` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_addDate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_firstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_lastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_add1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_zip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_optinUrlClean` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_IPClean` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_dateTime` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_dateStandard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duplicate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryLine1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryLine2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIPCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FullZIPCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Precision` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryPointBarcode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CarrierRoute` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountyFIPS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountyName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CongressionalDistrict` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Deliverable` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecordType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RDI` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CMRA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processingDate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suppressed_by_master_suppression` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `master_consumer_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quickiesuppressioncode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailUploadedOnQuickie` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MC` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsBadEMail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Domain_From_Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fgx_rdi` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fgx_Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ind_9090909` (`reg_email`),
  KEY `ind_90909address` (`reg_add1`),
  KEY `ind_999900_0090_I` (`DeliveryLine1`),
  KEY `ind_9090909999` (`state`),
  KEY `ind_9090909999Ti` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and..

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_pull_newconsumer_boatowners__Final` (
  `personfirstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personlastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primaryaddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondaryaddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cityname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZipCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ind_9099898778` (`Email`),
  KEY `dind_9099898778` (`primaryaddress`),
  KEY `dind_909008989` (`state`),
  KEY `inddd_909008989` (`cityname`),
  KEY `ind_090909` (`secondaryaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15499921 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you add indices to columns involved in the update?

Comment: Indexes are already added on all columns.

Comment: `IFNULL(xx,'')<>''` can probably be rewritten `xx <=> ''`.

Comment: Which table is `DeliveryLine1` in?  (Ditto for the other columns without qualification.)

Comment: Please change to the `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Comment: "Fields are properly Indexed" -- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @rick i edited the question with proper aliases and show create table.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: 16GB ram...12GB allotted to innodb_buffer_pool_Size

Comment: Moved tmp on the same drive where MySQL resides .. but still no improvements... even 3Million (Explain result = 3109381 rows * 1row ) rows table is taking 6+ hours  ;(

Comment: How many rows do you think there are with `a.primaryaddress=b.DeliveryLine1` ?

Comment: One of the tables does not have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`; this is generally not good.  (No, I don't see how it would explain the problem.)

Comment: `INDEX(DeliveryLine1, reg_lastname)` _might_ help with performance.

Comment: Added INDEX(DeliveryLine1, reg_lastname) but it doesn't help, still same number of rows being scanned

Comment: when it processes 100k rows in about 4 minutes why cant 3000k rows processed in 120 Minutes? i killed the query after 4 hours or so and now  i am updating rows by adding id check ...                                                                   AND a.id BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000;
Query OK, 30210 rows affected (3 min 53.36 sec)
Rows matched: 30210  Changed: 30210  Warnings: 0

Comment: its a dedicated server and nothing else is running on the server except this query, also if it still doing table scan why is it take that much time to scan few million rows, i strongly suspect some parameter issue in my.cnf

Comment: The index won't decrease the number of rows scanned, but may improve the speed.

Comment: How did you determine that 100K rows took 4 minutes (etc)?

Comment: to execute the query in chunks so that i doesnt get stuck I put a check on ID field ...where a.id between 1 and 10000 ....

Comment: i set   SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2, also is there any reason why CPU is standing at just 13% ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar Situation and I was save by Temporary Table. I inserted all on the temporary table and the use an update join  with the temporary table in order to update the originals tables. Surprising it went pretty fast.

Comment: That may be a workaround but whats the logic behind?